# Use data from a CSV file as values of a variable in a loop in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, loops, csv

I have the need to create a loop that collects data from a CSV file and use them as variables in an HTTP POST and I do not know how to do it, could any one help me with this problem?

The structure of the CSV:

```
name_active1, ip1, type1
name_active2, ip2, type2
name_active3, ip3, type3
...
```

And the variables would be

```
  $ NAME = name_active1
  $ IP = ip1
  $ TYPE = type1
```

And so on.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far ? Could you show us some code ? When asking a question, you are expected to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code before we can help you. Without it, questions about how to implement a feature or what code to write are deemed off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=', ' read -r NAME IP TYPE
do
    #You can do your processing here, e.g.
    echo "name=$NAME ip=$IP type=$TYPE"
done < data.csv

exit 0
```

Comment: Ups, your response is better, I didn't see.

Comment: It is just different, that's the good thing about programming :D

Comment: Personal taste - when I can, I like to use `IFS="$IFS,"` instead of hardcoding just a space. Sometimes you can't. *~shrug~*

Comment: By chance you will not know how to put a variable inside the body of an HTTP POST request? The problem is that it does not solve the variables

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    NAME=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}');
    IP=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}');
    TYPE=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $3}');
    echo "NAME=$NAME";
    echo "IP=$IP";
    echo "TYPE=$TYPE";
done < $1;
```

Comment: 'export' is not needed here, unless you want to make your variables visible to your entire environment. Even in such a case, only the last tuple of values will be stored and made available for new child processes.

Comment: Is there a reason you're executing `awk` three times on every record instead of just reading the line into the fields? (I'm sorry that sounds snarky - I honestly just thought there might be, though I can't see one...)

Comment: @PaulHodges Yes, there is a reason, my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Ah - then we have a lot in common. :) Fortunately, it's a failing we seem to be reducing as we go!